# What is this XAML in HTML 5 + CSS

Tags: wpf, html, silverlight, xaml, css

Does any body know how to achive the output of the XAML below to HTML5 and CSS3:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="33" />
        <RowDefinition Height="29" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="75" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="98" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="98" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="header" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border x:Name="mainNav" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border x:Name="secondNav" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border x:Name="body" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border x:Name="footer" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `-ms-grid` css property but [only on IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh673533(v=vs.85).aspx)... Otherwise, a lot of tutorials on [HTML5 begin with layout](https://www.google.fr/search?q=html5+layout).

Comment: Please look at this page, if you haven't already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx

Comment: HTML doesnt hold a candle to XAML. Try to convert this XAML to HTML: `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>`. Bottom line: html sucks

Comment: Hi, do you wish to do the "conversion" on the client side or the server side? Both are possible and fairly simple to implement.

Comment: it's not a conversion stuff, I need to have a collection of div structure's that render like this in XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want this code snipped translated to HTML/CSS. A one-to-one translation is shown below.

However, HTML/CSS is a different medium than XAML. E.g. there is no easy way to do `Width="*"` in CSS and there is no grid-system built in, so you have to build it with floats (this is for historical reasons, CSS was invented to style text documents, not build layouts). So I would recommend that you look at a more web-friendly solution: a widely-used HTML/CSS scaffolding framework with rows and columns is [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

Crude one-to-one translation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .grid > div > div {
        float: left;
        outline: 1px solid black;

        height: 100%;
        min-width: 30px;
    }

    .header {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .mainNav {
        height: 33px;
    }
    .secondNav {
        height: 29px;
    }
    .body {
        height: 30px;
    }
    .footer {
        height: 75px;
    }

    .grid-column-1 {
        width: 98px;
    }
    .grid-column-2 {
    }
    .grid-column-3 {
        width: 98px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="grid-column-1"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-2"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainNav">
            <div class="grid-column-1"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-2"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondNav">
            <div class="grid-column-1"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-2"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="grid-column-1"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-2"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="grid-column-1"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-2"></div>
            <div class="grid-column-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It gave me an idea how to do this layout stuff more easier. Bootstrap seems to be very interesting.. thanks again :)